# Sometimes get android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, cordova, android-fragments, phonegap

We're debugging a crash in a Cordova app that seems to happen on launch / foregrounding, after the app was backgrounded for a moderate amount of time and has been to some extent killed by the OS.

At the time of the crash the app is attempting to show a native dialog fragment for Fingerprint Authentication.  For some reason in this case the resources for this fragment cannot be found.

It's been reported for Android 6 and 7, on older and newer devices.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.koho/ca.koho.Koho}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2421)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5440)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1437)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2887)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1251)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
at com.cordova.plugin.android.fingerprintauth.FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.onCreateView(FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java:85)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1130)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1953)
at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:152)
at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:6279)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6287)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374)
... 9 more
```

Here's the problematic bit of code, from the `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateView`:

```
int fingerprint_dialog_container_id = getResources()
            .getIdentifier("fingerprint_dialog_container", "layout",
                    FingerprintAuth.packageName);
View v = inflater.inflate(fingerprint_dialog_container_id, container, false);
```

When the crash happens, `getIdentifier(...)` is for some reason returning 0.  Most of the time the actual identifier is returned.

I have not found a way to reproduce the crash, and advice to enable developer options like 'Don't keep activities' and 'Background process limit' had did not help.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: same for us ... did you make progress? THX